# How to add an SPF record in Webmin?

Tags: ubuntu, spf

I'm using VPS server with ubuntu 11.04 and webmin. And in one of my domain I'd like to use google apps, but neither in webmin panel nor in conf file I see a place to add this google spf record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Content of hosts file :

```
$ttl 38400
sy.com.tr.      IN      SOA     ns1.sy.com.tr. me.ugurbaltaci.com. (
                        1325710181
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
sy.com.tr.      IN      NS      ns1.sy.com.tr.
sy.com.tr.      IN      NS      ns2.sy.com.tr.
sy.com.tr.      IN      A       212.68.63.147
ns1.sy.com.tr.  IN      A       212.68.63.147
ns2.sy.com.tr.  IN      A       212.68.63.147
www.sy.com.tr.  IN      CNAME   sy.com.tr.
mail.sy.com.tr. IN      CNAME   ghs.google.com.
sy.com.tr.      IN      MX      1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
sy.com.tr.      IN      MX      5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
sy.com.tr.      IN      MX      5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
sy.com.tr.      IN      MX      10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
sy.com.tr.      IN      MX      10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a line:

```
sy.com.tr.  IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Note that you should list all domains that you send email from for your domain. If you have a web server sending email with your domain, then you need to include that server's IP as well.

Use a SPF setup wizard to help you get it right.

http://spfwizard.com/

Comment: Why not set `sy.com.tr.  IN      SPF     "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"`??

Comment: SPF RR's will work if your version of bind supports it. I think those were adding in bind 9.3 or 9.4.

Comment: If your version of BIND supports SPF type records, add both. A lot of mailing system are not yet geared to query the *actual* spf type, and thus cannot abide to the desired standard. During transitioning period from the current usage of TXT RR's to the use of SPF RR's, it is recommended that systems supporting both, actually has both types configured

Comment: @JudasIscariot1651  Is there an RFC on this recommendation?  For future compatibility it makes sense but not sure how far in the future that will be.  Just asking as we have clients on legacy systems that do not support SPF RRs yet.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408.txt section 3.1.1